# C# System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

пишу десктоп приложения на c#winforms при использовании bunufi framework, выскакивает ошибка System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
вот собственно код , помогите разобраться

```
namespace nowy_god
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton.StateProperties stateProperties1 = new Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton.StateProperties();
            this.loginwwod = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.parolwwod = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.pictureBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.bunifuButton1 = new Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // loginwwod
            // 
            this.loginwwod.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
            this.loginwwod.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(228, 172);
            this.loginwwod.Multiline = true;
            this.loginwwod.Name = "loginwwod";
            this.loginwwod.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(201, 40);
            this.loginwwod.TabIndex = 0;
            this.loginwwod.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.loginwwod_Enter);
            this.loginwwod.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.loginwwod_Leave);
            // 
            // parolwwod
            // 
            this.parolwwod.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
            this.parolwwod.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(228, 233);
            this.parolwwod.Multiline = true;
            this.parolwwod.Name = "parolwwod";
            this.parolwwod.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(201, 40);
            this.parolwwod.TabIndex = 1;
            this.parolwwod.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            this.parolwwod.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.parolwwod_Enter);
            this.parolwwod.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.parolwwod_Leave);
            // 
            // pictureBox3
            // 
            this.pictureBox3.Image = global::nowy_god.Properties.Resources.iconfinder_website___padlock_3440846;
            this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(179, 233);
            this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
            this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(43, 40);
            this.pictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.Image = global::nowy_god.Properties.Resources.iconfinder_website___male_user_3440844;
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(179, 172);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(43, 40);
            this.pictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = global::nowy_god.Properties.Resources.iconfinder_Cloud_storage_datatransfer_database_filetransfer_6071863__1_;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(275, 48);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 99);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // bunifuButton1
            // 
            this.bunifuButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.bunifuButton1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("bunifuButton1.BackgroundImage")));
            this.bunifuButton1.ButtonText = "Giris";
            this.bunifuButton1.ButtonTextMarginLeft = 0;
            this.bunifuButton1.DisabledBorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(161)))), ((int)(((byte)(161)))), ((int)(((byte)(161)))));
            this.bunifuButton1.DisabledFillColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.bunifuButton1.DisabledForecolor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuButton1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
            this.bunifuButton1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuButton1.IconLeftCursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.bunifuButton1.IconPadding = 10;
            this.bunifuButton1.IconRightCursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.bunifuButton1.IdleBorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(51)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))), ((int)(((byte)(183)))));
            this.bunifuButton1.IdleBorderRadius = 1;
            this.bunifuButton1.IdleBorderThickness = 0;
            this.bunifuButton1.IdleFillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(51)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))), ((int)(((byte)(183)))));
            this.bunifuButton1.IdleIconLeftImage = null;
            this.bunifuButton1.IdleIconRightImage = null;
            this.bunifuButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(242, 294);
            this.bunifuButton1.Name = "bunifuButton1";
            stateProperties1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(96)))), ((int)(((byte)(144)))));
            stateProperties1.BorderRadius = 1;
            stateProperties1.BorderThickness = 1;
            stateProperties1.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(96)))), ((int)(((byte)(144)))));
            stateProperties1.IconLeftImage = null;
            stateProperties1.IconRightImage = null;
            this.bunifuButton1.onHoverState = stateProperties1;
            this.bunifuButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 37);
            this.bunifuButton1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.bunifuButton1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.bunifuButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bunifuButton1_Click_1);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(654, 463);
            this.Controls.Add(this.bunifuButton1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.parolwwod);
            this.Controls.Add(this.loginwwod);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox loginwwod;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox parolwwod;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
        private Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton bunifuButton1;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `this.bunifuButton1 = new Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton()`

Comment: aepot, никак не помогает, в чем может быть ошибка, другие объекты bunifu такие же ошибки выдают                                                                                               
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

bunifuPages1 было null.

Comment: Тогда вам надо идти на github к автору библиотеки, и задавать этот вопрос там.